# O que tem de errado nesse código PHP?

Tags: php, revisão-de-código

```
if(count($items) > 1) {
    $out = array('success'=>false,'error'=>'You choose more bots');
} elseif($user['balance'] < $sum) {
    $out = array('success'=>false,'error'=>'You dont have coins! You have' echo $user['xxx']);
```

Comment: Sempre informe o máximo possível de informação para que as pessoas consigam lhe ajudar. Além do código que está gerando o erro, você deve também postar o erro que foi gerado.

Answer (score 5):

Acredito que não precise colocar o `echo`, tente fazer dessa maneira:

```
$out = array('success'=>false,'error'=>'You dont have coins! You have'.$user['xxx']);
```

Tente também com aspas duplas ao invés de aspas simples:

```
$out = array('success'=>false,'error'=>"You dont have coins! You have {$user['xxx']}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Existem 2 erros neste código, além de existir um `echo` na string, está faltando também o fechamento da tag elseif. Depois de `$sum)` tem a abertura `{`, mas o fechamento --> `}` está faltando. O código correto seria:

```
<?php

if( count($items) > 1)
{
    $out = array(
        'success' => false,
        'error'   => 'You choose more bots'
    );
}
elseif($user['balance'] < $sum)
{
    $out = array(
        'success' => false,
        'error'   => "You dont have coins! You have ${user['xxx']}" // <-- Estava escrito de maneira incorreta
    );
} // <-- Estava faltando

?>
```

> **Observação**: Utilizar `$user['xxx']` dentro de uma string com aspas duplas irá gerar um erro. O correto é `${user['xxx']}` ou `{$user['xxx']}`. Note a utilização das chaves.

Comment: na verdade tinha mais coisa pra baixo, e esse ] estava mais pra baixo. não coloquei o código inteiro só essa parte.